# Matplotlib: barh full width bars

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to generate a stacked horizontal bar chart in matplotlib. The issue I am facing is that the width of the bars does not fully fill the available width of the plotting area (additional space on the right).

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information on this online. 
What could I do to resolve this?

[Chart with additional space on the right of the bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoB6r.jpg)

```
measures = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B")

measure_bars = y_pos = np.arange(len(measures))
yes_data = [10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
number_of_answers = [20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
font = {'fontname': 'Arial', 'color': '#10384f'}

yes_data = [i / j * 100 for i, j in zip(yes_data, number_of_answers)]
no_data = [100 - i for i in yes_data]

bar_width = 0.6

plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False


fig = plt.figure()

plt.barh(measure_bars, yes_data, color='#89d329', height=bar_width, zorder=2)
plt.barh(measure_bars, no_data, left=yes_data, color='#ff3162', height=bar_width, zorder=3)

plt.grid(color=font["color"], zorder=0)
plt.yticks(measure_bars, measures, **font)
plt.title("TECHNICAL AND ORGANIZATIONAL MEASURES", fontweight="bold", size="16", x=0.5, y=1.1, **font)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())

ax.spines['bottom'].set_color(font["color"])
ax.spines['top'].set_color(font["color"])
ax.spines['right'].set_color(font["color"])
ax.spines['left'].set_color(font["color"])
ax.xaxis.label.set_color(font["color"])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors=font["color"])

for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_fontname(font["fontname"])

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.0, 100.1, 10))

plt.gca().legend(('Yes', 'No'), bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 0), ncol=2, shadow=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add (somewhere in the middle)

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
```